# InputStream left open from TimerTask call to Guava map; GlassFish complains on undeploy

Tags: java, glassfish-3, guava, timertask, servlet-listeners

I'm implementing [ServletContextListener](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/servlet/2.5/docs/servlet-2_5-mr2/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) in order to schedule various jobs on my app server (GlassFish 3.1). I'm using `contextInitialized()` to schedule recurring tasks, and  `contextDestroyed()` to call cleanup methods, such as shutting down c3p0:

```
public class JobScheduler implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        //schedule TimerTasks
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        //cancel TimerTasks
        //cleanup methods
    }
}
```

When I cancel the `TimerTask`s, I have added logic that waits for any running tasks to finish before continuing, to make sure nothing is still executing when I clean up resources.

Getting to my question: when I undeploy my application, I'm seeing one or two of these warnings being displayed in GlassFish output:

```
WARNING: Input stream has been finalized or forced closed without being explicitly closed; stream instantiation reported in following stack trace
java.lang.Throwable
    at com.sun.enterprise.loader.ASURLClassLoader$SentinelInputStream.<init>(ASURLClassLoader.java:1230)
    at com.sun.enterprise.loader.ASURLClassLoader$InternalJarURLConnection.getInputStream(ASURLClassLoader.java:1338)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$Loader.getResource(URLClassPath.java:503)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getResource(URLClassPath.java:169)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:194)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    at com.google.common.base.FinalizableReferenceQueue$DecoupledLoader.loadFinalizer(FinalizableReferenceQueue.java:228)
    at com.google.common.base.FinalizableReferenceQueue.loadFinalizer(FinalizableReferenceQueue.java:155)
    at com.google.common.base.FinalizableReferenceQueue.<clinit>(FinalizableReferenceQueue.java:84)
    at com.google.common.collect.CustomConcurrentHashMap$QueueHolder.<clinit>(CustomConcurrentHashMap.java:651)
    at com.google.common.collect.CustomConcurrentHashMap$WeakValueReference.<init>(CustomConcurrentHashMap.java:1589)
    at com.google.common.collect.CustomConcurrentHashMap$Strength$3.referenceValue(CustomConcurrentHashMap.java:322)
    at com.google.common.collect.CustomConcurrentHashMap.newValueReference(CustomConcurrentHashMap.java:1731)
    at com.google.common.collect.CustomConcurrentHashMap$Segment.setValue(CustomConcurrentHashMap.java:2050)
    at com.google.common.collect.CustomConcurrentHashMap$Segment.put(CustomConcurrentHashMap.java:2430)
    at com.google.common.collect.CustomConcurrentHashMap.put(CustomConcurrentHashMap.java:3346)
    at MyProject.CacheEngine$MyCustomCache$1.apply(CacheEngine.java:244)
    at MyProject.CacheEngine$MyCustomCache$1.apply(CacheEngine.java:237)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingValueReference.compute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:316)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingSegment.compute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:140)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap.apply(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:71)
    at com.google.common.collect.MapMaker$ComputingMapAdapter.get(MapMaker.java:848)

    //stacktrace of the Runnable called by TimerTask, leading up to a call to Guava ComputingMap

    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:512)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:462)
```

From what I can tell, GlassFish is complaining about an `InputStream` that was never explicitly closed, which was opened by a `ClassLoader` for a `Finalizer` called by one of my Guava `MapMaker`-created computing maps, which is being accessed by the task. **Note that the stack trace above is not that of an exception, but the actual trace from the running task to the stream's instantiation.**

What I need help with is understanding why this `InputStream` is being left open even though I'm waiting for all tasks to finish, and whether or not I can better handle its cleanup. It seems to be specifically related to Guava's computing maps that you can see in the stack trace.

**Update:** I still get the same warnings if I use `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` instead of `TimerTask`

**Update 2:** Tumbleweeded

Comment: How does your code where you manage timer tasks look like?

Comment: Without any detail on what is the TimerTask doing, it is hard to suggest a solution.
Specifically, are there any Streams, Sockets or Files open by the task?

Comment: @hidralisk - The codebase is too complex to show here. As you can see though, the stacktrace from the warning shows how the stream is instantiated.

Comment: So, the "cleanup code" closes the Stream? does the cleanup code actually get executed? Could it be a bug in the library you are using?

Comment: @hidralisk - The cleanup code just cancels the tasks. I have no visibility of the stream mentioned by the warning - it's buried deep within the calls to Guava's computing maps, which are used not just by the scheduled tasks but the entire codebase. I'll post the cleanup code for the tasks later tonight.

Comment: probably need to use a newer version of the library, following from the guava java docs: FinalizableReferenceQueue()
Deprecated. 
FinalizableReferenceQueue is an unsound mechanism for cleaning up references, because (1) it's single thread can be easily overloaded, and (2) it's insistance on running a background thread is problematic in certain environments. This class is scheduled for deletion in December 2012.

Comment: @hidralisk Huh, that's interesting. Would you mind posting that as an answer? My code is indeed using an older Guava version (9.0), so sounds like it might solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably need to use a newer version of the library, the following is from the guava java docs:

```
FinalizableReferenceQueue() Deprecated.
```

> FinalizableReferenceQueue is an unsound mechanism for cleaning up references, because
>   (1) it's single thread can be easily overloaded, and
>   (2) it's insistence on running a background thread is problematic in certain environments. This class is scheduled for deletion in December 2012.

Comment: Unfortunately I no longer have access to the code that I could confirm this as a fix, but it seems like `FinalizableReferenceQueue` was probably the issue here. Marking as accepted.